# Правильное выделение памяти под структуру.

Tags: c, структуры

Решаю задачки с Codefights и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть структура, которая в задаче определена следующим образом

```
// Definition for arrays:
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
```

Прототип функции определен следующим образом

```
arr_arr_integer minesweeper(arr_arr_boolean matrix)
```

То есть в качестве аргумента ей передается структура, содержащая указатель на двумерный массив типа bool, а вернуться должна структура с массивом, содержащим int.

Пытаюсь выделить память под структуру следующим образом

```
arr_arr_integer rez;

rez.arr = calloc(1, sizeof(arr_integer));
rez.size = matrix.size;

for (int i = 0; i < rez.size; i++)
{
  rez.arr[i].arr = calloc(matrix.arr->size, sizeof(int));
  rez.arr[i].size = matrix.arr->size;
}

return rez;
```

Просто, чтобы посмотреть, что вернется. Результаты следующие. Для input

```
[[true,false,false], 
 [false,true,false], 
 [false,false,false]]
```

возвращается

```
[[3,0,19006432], 
[0,0,0], 
[0,0,0]]
```

Для Input

```
[[false,false,false], 
 [false,false,false]]
```

результат

```
[[0,0,0], 
[0,0,0]]
```

Для input

```
[[true,false,false,true], 
 [false,false,true,false], 
 [true,true,false,true]]
```

Результат

```
[[4,0,19006928,0], 
[0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0]]
```

(calloc не возвращает NULL ни в одном случае).

Если я пытаюсь переопределить элемент rez.arr[0].arr[2] для первого и третьего случаев, код вылетает с ошибкой.

Если я переопределяю rez.arr[0].arr[0] (например = 0), то Output для первого случая выглядит так

```
[[0,0,14504928], 
[0,0,0], 
[]]
```

Собственно вопросы
1. Как правильно выделить память?
2. Откуда берутся эти мусорные значения?
3. Почему для второго случая все срабатывает правильно?

Comment: Покажите для лучшего понимания вопроса, как _конкретно_ реализованы у вас структуры `arr_arr_integer` и `arr_arr_boolean` без всяких частей препроцессинга, если можно :)

Comment: Если бы я это знал, то, возможно, у меня бы не возникал подобный вопрос. К сожалению на Codefights не слишком много информации о том как реализованы тесты (в отличие от того же Codewars). Так что о структурах я знаю ровно то, что описано в самом начале вопроса в виде комментария.

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Теперь другой вопрос : с чего вы взяли, что здесь работа с матрицей? Сами поля структуры и функция под ней указывают, что здесь работа с одномерным массивом + в вашей функции вы аллоцируете память для одномерного массива, а пытаетесь вывести матрицу :) Можете определиться, пожалуйста, какие у вас исходные данные, а что нужно получить в итоге? Может, как вариант, ваша задача превратить обычный массив `arr_bool` в `arr_int` ?